# Understanding the term upper bound?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, relaxations

I am trying to understand the meaning or intuition of **upper bound** in the following sentence:

The relaxed problem is **upper bound** of the original problem.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We'd need more context to be sure, but it probably means that the solution to an instance of the relaxed problem is an upper bound on the solution to the corresponding instance of the original problem.

Comment: Thanks sir for your response....but what is meant by upper bound....Can u please tell me in layman term...I am actually not getting the sense of this sentence....

Comment: "$a$ is an upper bound on $b$" means "$a\ge b$".

Comment: Did you understand the comment? We need the surrounding sentences.

Comment: Yes sir ....now I understood ....Thank u so much for clearing my doubt...

Comment: Then in case of lower bound can I say " $a$ is an lower bound on $b$ " means "$a \leq b$" ?

Comment: An upper bound of a set $S$ is a value $u$ such that for each $s\in S$, $s\le u$. But that might not be what this means. What is the general problem and what is the restricted problem? I ask because authors will sometimes use a mathematical term to be clever rather than use its precise meaning.